# Apply function to column in pandas dataframe that takes two arguments

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a certain mapping:

```
mapping = {
    'cat': 'purrfect',
    'dog': 'too much work',
    'fish': 'meh'
    }
```

and a `dataframe`:

```
    animal  name       description
0   cat     sparkles   NaN
1   dog     rufus      NaN
2   fish    mr. blub   NaN
```

I would like to programmatically fill in the `description` column using the `animal` column and `mapping` dict as inputs:

```
def describe_pet(animal,mapping):
    return mapping[animal]
```

When I try to use pandas `apply()` function:

```
df['description'].apply(describe_pet,args=(df['animal'],mapping))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: describe_pet() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

It seems like using `apply()` is trivial passing one argument to the function. How can I do it with two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested answer solves your specific problem, but for the more generic case:

The `args` parameter is for parameters in addition to the columns:

> args : tuple Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to
>   the array/series

[pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the `map` method without writing a function or using `apply` at all:

```
df['description'] = df.animal.map(mapping)
```

Comment: that is very elegant and is certainly best for my particular situation.  Ophir Yoktan's answer applies to the more general question.