# How to define multiple column values and call using .map function?

Tags: python, pandas

> Using the code below I need to place the values ("Right Data, Incorrect Data...) into a column "Assessment" when the if condition satisfies based on x and y values. But I am getting the below error

**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'**

```
def variable(x,y):
    x = df['Volume']
    y = df['Turnover']
    if df[(x==0) & (y==0)]:
        return 'Right Data'
    if df[(x>0) & (y>0)]:
        return 'Right Data'
    if df[(x<0) & (y<0)]:
        return 'Right Data'
    if df[(x>0) & (y<0)]:
        return 'Incorrect Data'
    if df[(x<0) & (y>0)]:
        return 'Incorrect Data'
    if df[(x!=0) & (y==0)]:
        return 'Incorrect Data'
    if df[(x==0) & (y!=0)]:
        return 'Incorrect Data'
    if df[(x==0) & (y.isnull())]:
        return 'Missing Data'
    if df[(x=='Nan') & (y!=0)]:
        return 'Missing Data'
test = df[['Volume','Turnover']]
test2 = test.map(variable)
df['Assessment'] = test2
```

Comment: use `test.applymap(variable)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Comment: it is giving below TypeError: ("variable() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'", 'occurred at index Volume')

Comment: yes I did the way you suggested I got the above mentioned error after doing that, I am not sure how to call both x and y using the map function?

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182744/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series

Comment: if it is only one column variable X then we can do it the way you suggested, but in this case I need to check 2 columns simultaneously and then change the values in new column when both columns satisfies the condition

Comment: yup, i know, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lambda for this:

```
df['Assessment'] = df.apply(lambda x: variable(x['Volume'], x['Turnover']), axis=1)
```

Source:

[python pandas- apply function with two arguments to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279378/python-pandas-apply-function-with-two-arguments-to-columns)