# get operation on list as new column in pandas containing list or strings

Tags: python, pandas, list

Assume this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['texttext',[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]],
                   'b':['texttext',[1,2,5,8,9,10],[2,3,5]]})
```

I would like to get three extra columns that get:
a) the common values of the list intercetcion
b) the values en list of column a not in column b
c) the values in column c not in column a

Note that the df might contain (like in row 1) other NON LIST values.
That makes things complicated

I now how to make the operations for the lists:

```
common = [x for x in lst1 if x in lst2]
minus = [x for x in lst1 if x not in lst2]
plus = [x for x in lst2 if x not in lst1]
```

But I am not able to figure out how to implement it in pandas.
even for a method (for .apply) I have to sent two values
In a one liner I have to check the type.

Some idea?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
Expected output:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({'a':['texttext',[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]],
                     'b':['texttext',[1,2,5,8,9,10],[2,3,5]],
                    'common':['',[2,5],[2,3,5]],
                    'minus':['',[3,4,5],[4]],
                    'plus':['',[ 8, 9, 10],[]]})
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3L1g.png]

Comment: Why don't you include the expected output **as table**?

Comment: Your table is weird because first line is a string, and the others are list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define a function to test the membership of lists in column `a` with the corresponding lists in column `b`:

```
def test_membership():
    for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b']):
        if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
            a, b = set(a), set(b)
            yield list(a & b), list(a - b), list(b - a)
        else:
            yield '', '', ''

df[['common', 'minus', 'plus']] = list(test_membership())
```

---

```
                 a                    b     common   minus        plus
0         texttext             texttext                               
1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10]  [1, 2, 5]  [3, 4]  [8, 9, 10]
2     [2, 3, 4, 5]            [2, 3, 5]  [2, 3, 5]     [4]          []
```

Answer (score 0):

For what's about using two columns as an input to the apply function you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279378/python-pandas-apply-function-with-two-arguments-to-columns/34279543).
To check if your object is a list, use the builtin

```
isinstance(your_variable,list)
```

This should be the right building blocks for your problem.